# BlueStack4 showing bottom part black - MAC

Tags: mac, android, bluestacks

I have installed BlueStack Version 4.90.0 (2809), and MAC OS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132).

Normal BlueStack display shows proper Android interface but when I move to the full screen, it shows the bottom part as a black screen and stays as it is.

[image]

You can see in the above image that 1/4th portion of the BlueStack shows a black screen and Android interface uses 3/4the of the screen.

Tried below solution:

1. Edited plist file of BlueStack and change width & height
2. Tried all the different resolution from preferences
3. Reinstall again.

None of all the above works. Does anyone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall Bluestacks and restart your system, then reinstall a fresh version of BlueStacks 4.0 (Mac) from it's [official website](https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000735272-Introducing-the-BlueStacks-App-Player-for-Mac) or one of the legit sources for [Bluestacks](https://download.zone/bluestacks-4-download/).